# How to join a column using two other columns?

Tags: python, join, indexing

I have one table that gives gives me a VALUE based on the Month and Type of Residential Property.

[image: table 1]

and I have a second table that also contains Month (Date of Sale (dd/mm/yyyy)) and Type of Residential Property.
[image: table 2]
I would use Month and Date of Sale (dd/mm/yyyy) as an index to join VALUE on to table 2 but Dublin and non Dublin properties both get a date each. How can I link VALUE onto table 2 using both columns?

On option I thought of is to concatenate Month and Type of Residential Property to make a unique index but was hoping for a simpler method. Thanks!

Comment: How is this data represented *in Python*?

Comment: Month is in datetime and Type of Residential Property is an object.

Comment: And the *tables* themselves?

Answer (score 1):

What about using [pandas.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `on=['Month', 'Type of Residential Property`] ? This way you can merge both tables based on those variables, including the VALUE.

Here is an example with similar tables. Let's say your first table is as follows: [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXmgp.png) and your second table is: [df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yaZ1.png). Then using `df2.merge(df, on=['Month', 'Type of Residential Property'])` will get you this final dataframe: [final df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiPg3.png). For this to work, you will need to rename the column `Date of Sale` in `df2` to `Month` (or the reverse: rename the column `Month` in `df` to `Date of Sale`).

Here is the code for this example:

> 

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':'2010-01-01', 'Type of Residential
Property': 'Dublin', 'UNIT': 'Base 2015=100', 'VALUE':96.1},
index=[1203])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Month':'2010-01-01', 'Adress': '5
Braemor Drive', 'Price': '343,000,000', 'Type of Residential
Property': 'Dublin'}, index=[0])

df2.merge(df, on=['Month', 'Type of Residential Property'])
```

Comment: please provide an example